# Create Site Column (lookup type) 

Tags: site-column, feature, feature-activation, lookup-column, list

Is there any solid (proven) method of creating Site columns (lookups) where list GUID is not known?

I think this is where feature activation kicks in; getting the lookup list by its name and then using the GUID to create the lookup.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't too difficult really, in the FeatureActivated method, you just create a new SPieldLookup (using [SPWeb.Fields.AddLookup()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436747.aspx) for the SPSite's RootWeb), and set the properties for the [SPFieldLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookup_members.aspx) as required.

First time doing it? Bit tricky if you've never made a FeatureReceiver before, let me know if you need a tutorial do that,  and here's some sample code that should get you started (this will create a field that matches to "Title" of "My List") [also, this needs to be a FeatureReceiver for a Site Collection -scoped Feature];

```
SPWeb oWeb = ((SPSite)Feature.Parent).OpenWeb();

SPList oList = oWeb.Lists["My List"];

oWeb.Fields.AddLookup("My Lookup Column", oList.Id, false);

SPFieldLookup lkp = (SPFieldLookup)oWeb.Fields["my Lookup Column"];

lkp.LookupField = "Title";

lkp.Update();
```

Comment: Thanks James. I have used featureactivation. These fields are for site collection and the lists I will be using are also on site collection. A good tutorial or link would really help.

Comment: This might help: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-programmatically-provisioning-lookup-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article:

[Declaratively adding a lookup field to a list schema using the name of the referenced list](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/declaratively-adding-a-lookup-field-to-a-list-schema-using-the-name-of-the-referenced-list/)